# Exclude current page from list of pages

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm using [catlist categorypage=yes post_type=page] in the sidebar to display a list of pages with the same category as the current page.  Wonderful, but it returns a link to the current page.

Is there a simple way to exclude the current page from the results?

Comment: You're using a shortcode. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so.

I think this is the plugin you're using:
https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts

The doc says you can use `excludeposts`, so you'd use:

```
[catlist categorypage=yes post_type=page excludeposts=<ID_OF_PAGE>]
```

Comment: Yes, @Kelley van Evert is right, it is [List-Category-Posts](https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts).

Comment: Yes, @Kelley van Evert is right, it is [List-Category-Posts](https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts).
The shortcode is in a widget on all pages, so excludeposts would be fine if it would retrieve the current page id, but I don't think it will accept a variable.

Comment: I see. I forked and pull-requested a little fix for that @ github, but that probably won't change your situation quickly.
A second solution would be to use javascript. The displayed post ID is always present as a javascript variable, and you could also get the title; Now if you could identify the link via CSS, using the title and/or ID, then you could remove it with javascript. Could you give us an example of generated markup?

Comment: Hey kelly, I was looking at the code yesterday and had thought of extending excludeposts, to take a value of 'this' in addition to the IDs as current "[catlist excludeposts=this,52,37]" - either way, I'll probably patch my version of the plugin until the owner gets an update.  It feels like a fairly basic requirement.

Comment: Just a heads up to let you know I fixed this on the plugin. It's currently working on the Github version so a new release with this and other changes will be available soon: 0.24